# Symfony 2 : ContextErrorException: Notice: serialize():"url" returned as member variable from __sleep() but does not exist in

Tags: php, symfony

I'm working in a project that has been already started, and i'm continuing in, I got this exception when I added a property in an entity , this poperty is a simple column that get it's values from another entity (personnal), and it's a multi select value, the render of the new page has no problem but when I submit, I got this Exception, the field I added is this :

```
/**
 * @var array
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="responsable",type="array",  nullable=true)
 * 
 */
private $responsable;


 /**
 * Add responsable
 *
 * @param $responsable
 * @return Actionreclamation
 */
public function addResponsable($responsable)
{

    if (!in_array($responsable, $this->responsable, true)) {
        $this->responsable[] = $responsable;
    }

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove responsable
 *
 * @param $responsable
 */
public function removeResponsable( $responsable)
{
//    $this->responsable->removeElement($responsable);
     if (false !== $key = array_search($responsable, $this->responsable, true)) {
        unset($this->responsable[$key]);
        $this->responsable = array_values($this->responsable);
    }

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get responsable
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getResponsable()
{
    return $this->responsable;
}

/**
 * Set responsable
 *
 * @param array $responsable
 * @return Actionreclamation
 */
public function setResponsable($responsable)
{
    $this->responsable = $responsable;

    return $this;
}
```

and inside the form type :

```
->add('responsable', 'entity', array(
            'class'    => 'UserUserBundle:Personnel',
            'property' => 'nompersonnel',
            'multiple' => true ))
```

inside the view :

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Responsable</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="input-icon right">                                       
                            <i class="fa"></i> 
                             {{ form_widget(form.responsable) }}
                        </div>
                        <span class="help-block">{{ form_errors(form.responsable) }}</span>     
                    </div>
                </div>
```

plz I need help!

the exception is :

```
in C:\wamp\www\GESTIBAT0.1\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\ArrayType.php line 38
at ErrorHandler->handle('8', 'serialize(): &quot;url&quot; returned as member variable from __sleep() but does not exist', 'C:\wamp\www\GESTIBAT0.1\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\ArrayType.php', '38', array('value' => array(object(Personnel), object(Personnel)), 'platform' => object(MySqlPlatform)))
at serialize(array(object(Personnel), object(Personnel))) in C:\wamp\www\GESTIBAT0.1\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\ArrayType.php line 38
at ArrayType->convertToDatabaseValue(array(object(Personnel), object(Personnel)), object(MySqlPlatform)) in C:\wamp\www\GESTIBAT0.1\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Statement.php line 98
at Statement->bindValue('6', array(object(Personnel), object(Personnel)), 'array') in C:\wamp\www\GESTIBAT0.1\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister.php line 273
at BasicEntityPersister->executeInserts() in C:\wamp\www\GESTIBAT0.1\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php line 929
at UnitOfWork->executeInserts(object(ClassMetadata)) in C:\wamp\www\GESTIBAT0.1\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php line 318
at UnitOfWork->commit(null) in C:\wamp\www\GESTIBAT0.1\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager.php line 355
at EntityManager->flush() in C:\wamp\www\GESTIBAT0.1\src\Client\ClientBundle\Controller\ActionreclamationController.php line 56
at ActionreclamationController->createAction(object(Request))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ActionreclamationController), 'createAction'), array(object(Request))) in C:\wamp\www\GESTIBAT0.1\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 2843
at HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1') in C:\wamp\www\GESTIBAT0.1\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 2817
at HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true) in C:\wamp\www\GESTIBAT0.1\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 2946
at ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true) in C:\wamp\www\GESTIBAT0.1\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 2248
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in C:\wamp\www\GESTIBAT0.1\web\app_dev.php line 28
```

thanx in advance!

"Edit"
The main entity is named "ActionReclamation" it has a field (simple column with no relation as varchar in the database) named "responsable" the values for this field are returned from another entity named "Personnel", in the view I show the values of "Personnel" entity and I can choose multiple values

Did I explain well ?
thanx for help

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your model has evolved, and you removed a "url" property from one of your class (Responsable).

So when Doctrine try to unserialize your value (stored as an "array" type), he don't know what to do with this "url" property...

Comment: I've an apload field when inserting values in the other fields and if just i put the cursor in the upload field and submit after that, I got this exception and if I do not touch it I got the same exception but with a name of another field which is "matricule"

Comment: ContextErrorException: Notice: serialize(): "matriculepersonnel" returned as member variable from __sleep() but does not exist in C:\wamp\www\GESTIBAT0.1\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\ArrayType.php line 38

Comment: Can you edit your post, putting your Doctrine mapping information for your entities ?

Comment: plz if I need to post something to clarify the question, tell me plz

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this :

```
php bin/console doctrine:mongodb:generate:hydrators
```

Comment: please expand on what issue the OP is having and how this solves it

Comment: As Yann Eugoné said, the issue is that the model has been modified.
I got this issue too, and solved it by simply making an update of hydrators and proxies by generating them
It works like a charm to me :)